# Cordova + JQuery + IndexedDB how to make a simple .add() & .get()?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, indexeddb

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around all the different syntax from all the examples I have seen. I have even tried modifying a [working example](https://greenido.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/how-to-use-indexeddb-simplest-example/), but the example does so many things at once that I don’t understand it all to be able to break it down.

Can someone please write out a simple copy/paste working example of how you create a db and then interact with it using IndexedDB? All I want is a input/button that will save a value to the db and then a second button that will print the value to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I did up an example where you enter text in a textbox that is written to indexeddb on save.  It then fetches that data from the db and places it in a

tag.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="dataGoesHere" placeholder="item to be saved"/> 
    <button id="clickme">Save</button>
    <div id="saved"></div>
    </br>
    <input type="text" id="loadData" placeholder="type item here" /> 
    <button id="loadme">Load</button>
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type="text" id="updateData" placeholder="loaded item to update" /> 
    <button id="updateme">Update</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
(function ($, window, document) {

  myDb = function () {
    var name = "test",
    version = "1",
    db,
    testStoreName = "exampleStore",
    testIndexName = "testIndexName",
    addToTestIndex = false,

    init = function () {
      var deferred = $.Deferred(),
      openRequest = indexedDB.open(name, version);

      openRequest.onupgradeneeded = dbUpgrade;
      openRequest.onsuccess = dbOpen;
      openRequest.onerror = dbError;

      return deferred.promise();

      function dbUpgrade(evt) {
        //here our db is at evt.target.result here we can adjust stores and indexes
        var thisDb = evt.target.result, //the current db we are working with
        newStore = thisDb.createObjectStore(testStoreName, {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
        //Using indexes, you can target specific keys, this can be an array!
        newStore.createIndex("testIndexKey", "testIndexKey", {unique : false});
        newStore.createIndex("item", "item", {unique : false});
        console.log("Doing an upgrade");
      }

      function dbOpen(evt) {
        console.log("DB successfully opened");
        db = evt.target.result;
        deferred.resolve();
      }

      function dbError(error) {
        console.log("DB Error");
        console.log(error);
        deferred.reject(error);
      }
    },

    add = function(item) {
      var itemToAdd = {"item" : item},
      objStore,
      request,
      deferred = $.Deferred();
      if (!addToTestIndex) {
        addToTestIndex = !addToTestIndex;
        itemToAdd.testIndexKey = "This is a test";
      }

      //first get the object store with the desired access
      objStore = db.transaction([testStoreName], "readwrite").objectStore(testStoreName);
      //next create the request to add it
      request = objStore.add(itemToAdd);
        request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
            deferred.resolve(evt.target.result);
        };

          request.onerror = function (evt) {
            deferred.reject(evt);
        };

      return deferred.promise();
    },

    get = function (index) {
      //Since our store uses an int as a primary key, that is what we are getting
      //The cool part is when you start using indexes...
      var deferred = $.Deferred(),
      store = db.transaction([testStoreName], "readonly").objectStore(testStoreName),
      request = store.get(parseInt(index));

      request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        deferred.resolve(evt.target.result);
      };

      request.onerror = function (evt) {
        deferred.reject("DBError: could not get " + index + " from " + testStoreName);
      };

      return deferred.promise();
      };

    getItem = function (itemText) {
      //Since our store uses an int as a primary key, that is what we are getting
      //The cool part is when you start using indexes...
      var deferred = $.Deferred(),
      store = db.transaction([testStoreName], "readonly").objectStore(testStoreName),
      testIndex = store.index("item"),
      request = testIndex.getKey(itemText);

      request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        deferred.resolve(evt.target.result);
      };

      request.onerror = function (evt) {
        deferred.reject("DBError: could not get " + index + " from " + testStoreName);
      };

      return deferred.promise();
      };

      put = function (item) {
      var deferred = $.Deferred(),
      store = db.transaction([testStoreName], "readwrite").objectStore(testStoreName),
      request = store.put(item);

      request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        deferred.resolve(evt.target.result);
      };

      request.onerror = function (evt) {
        deferred.reject("DBError: could not get " + index + " from " + testStoreName);
      };

      return deferred.promise();
      }

      indexedDB.deleteDatabase('test');

    return {
      init: init,
      get: get,
      getItem: getItem,
      add: add,
      put: put
    };
  }

  var db = new myDb(),
  itemToUpdate;
  db.init().then(function () {
    $("#clickme").click(function(evt) {
      console.log("Adding new item to db");
      db.add($("#dataGoesHere").val())
      .then(function (res) {
        return db.get(res);
      })
      .then(function (res) {
        $('#saved').append('<p>'+res.item+'</p>');
      });
    });

    $("#loadme").click(function(evt) {
      db.getItem($("#loadData").val())
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log("Have our index:");
        console.log(res);
        return db.get(res);
      })
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log("Fetched to populate update input:")
        console.log(res);
        itemToUpdate = res;
        $('#updateData').val(itemToUpdate.item);
      });
    });

    $("#updateme").click(function(evt) {
      itemToUpdate.item = $('#updateData').val();
      db.put(itemToUpdate)
      .then(function(res) {
        console.log("Item should be updated");
        console.log(res);
      })
    });
  })



})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Plunker you can play with: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zxh7KYGylyZNYGTVKsQl?p=preview

You really have to deal with the callbacks, that is the tricky part.  I also try to outline indexes.  You can use these to quickly to perform a reduce your dataset, and can have cursor's opened for, or be fetched from directly.

EDIT:
Alright, a lot of copy pasta code in there, but I updated the example.  Begin by saving a value.  Type the item to load, which will populate the update input.  Change that input to update the value.

Again, the tricky part is wrapping your head around the fact that it is async, where something like localStorage is not.  Using promises you can easily mimic the behavior of something like localStorage (as you reference in the comment thread,) but indexeddb also offers reductions over your dataset (among many other features.)

Comment: The example you gave does pretty much what i asked for short of having a button that retrieves the data instead of placing it at the end of the save command.  I have been looking at it and i am still confused tho as i seem to be unable to change the index. I have tried to change it from "testIndexKey" to something else, but it keeps going to the same location... thoughts?

Comment: my end goal is to do as followed. 1- check if anything exists. 2- add something to the database. 3- retrieve something from the database. 4 update a entry that was pulled from the step 1 check

Comment: I'll try to clarify the part about the indexes.  The first parameter of the index is the index's name.  The second parameter is a single or array of keys that is used for the reduce on your db.  In this instance I tried to highlight this by only adding every other item with that key.  `1- check if anything exists` the oncomplete will be called with an empty result if it does not exist, otherwise it will hold the item.  I think 2 and 3 are briefly covered, and four is done with a put call.  We fetch the item, then execute: `objectStore.put(item);`  I will look at adding these to the example.

Comment: Ugg i cant seem to format my response well.


Is there a way to interact with the data like localstorage?
I am looking for something like  

on load look for data..if data exists then append each one.  

data.each(function(index) {  
 append(data($(this).val()))  
});  
  
  
then have something like this.  
  
//save data  
$("#adddata").click(function() {  
 savedata(key,$(this).val())  
});  
  
//get data   
$("#getdata").click(function() {  
 data($(this).val())  
});  
  
//update data  
$("#updatedata").click(function() {  
 savedata($(this).val(),$("#updatedata").val())  
});